# Dataframe with a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to make a for loop, where I can create and modify dataframes. The input is a messy data frames, That i want to clean, break into smaller data frames, and merge them togheter. The output would be a clean df.
I found a way for making them but I can't find a way for calling them back after that, in the loop, or another one.

```
for (i in 1992:2015) {
df<-filter(altdf, date== i)

df<-data.frame(df) 

sumdf<- lm(y~log(x), df)
sumdf<-summary(sumdf)


sumdf<-data.frame(sumdf$coefficients)


sumdf<- pivot_longer(sumdf, cols= 1:4, names_to = 'Results', values_to = 'year' )


sumdf$year<-as.numeric(sumdf$year)

assign(paste0('years', i, sep = ''),sumdf) 

}
```

and now i need to access the df I made with 'assign', to continue to modify them.
Do you have any idea how I can make that ?

Comment: Hi Marine, your question is far too vague to be answerable. Please provide a reproducible example with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I made a list of all the dataframes, with `lapply`:

```r
df_list <- lapply(ls(pattern = "df"), function(x) get(x))
```